# What happens when my opponent sinks the black ball by hand?

Tags: rules, pool

If my opponent sinks the black ball by their hand, do I win or carry on playing?

Comment: This is an interesting question in a way. I am not sure how the rules would be interpreted if the hand accidentally put the 8-ball into the pocket. Reading the answer provided by @dly I would say loss of frame. But, if it was deliberate, then in tournaments I play it would be considered bad sportsmanship which could attract league penalties and definitely loss of frame. There could be allowances made in non-professional tournaments for accident but that would be down to the league rules

Answer (score 1):

You win.

There are different rule sets, but usually they're equal when it comes to illegally pocketing black: The opponent wins that game.

[Example:](http://www.vnea.com/8-ball-rules.aspx)

> F. LOSS OF GAME
>
> 1. **Pocketing the 8-ball when it is not the legal object ball except on an opening break.**
> 2. Pocketing the 8-ball on the same stroke as the last of his group of balls.
> 3. Jumping or knocking the 8-ball off the table at any time.
> 4. Pocketing the 8-ball in a pocket other than the one designated.
> 5. Fouling while (pocketing) the 8-ball in the designated pocket.
> 6. Third infraction of the slow play rule.
> 7. Pocketing the 8-ball and the cue ball on the break stroke. (This varies, if your league considers an 8-ball break a win.)
> 8. Not correctly marking the pocket while pocketing the 8-ball.